# Dropping constraints to update tables - Current transaction is aborted

Tags: postgresql, transactions, constraints

Context: I want to update a table called "Projects" and change the project number from 10 to 45 where the project name is "Website". This Project table has a PK (pnumber attribute) and its related to another table called "WorksOn" that has a FK (attribute pno) related to the primary key pnumber of Project table.

The diagram would be something like this:

[image]

I was trying something like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    ALTER TABLE Workson DROP CONSTRAINT fk_workson_projects;
    ALTER TABLE Projects DROP CONSTRAINT pk_projects;
    UPDATE Projects
        SET pnumber = 45
    WHERE pname = 'Website';
    ALTER TABLE Workson ADD CONSTRAINT fk_workson_projects FOREIGN KEY (pno) REFERENCES projects(pnumber);
    ALTER TABLE Projects ADD CONSTRAINT pk_projects PRIMARY KEY (pnumber);

COMMIT;
```

Essentially dropping the constraints, updating the table and adding the same constraints again but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
SQL state: 25P02
```

How could I update the information by dropping the constraints and adding them back again inside a transaction?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the primary key *before* you can create a foreign key that references it. Looking at the error messages would have told you that.

Comment: Hi thank you for the input, I keep getting this error: `ERROR:  insert or update on table "workson" violates foreign key constraint "fk_workson_projects"
DETAIL:  Key (pno)=(10) is not present in table "projects".
SQL state: 23503`

Comment: I was able to update from 10 to 45, but now the foreign key hasn't updated

Comment: Look at the *first* error message. The one you are showing is not the relevant one.